# Vue Router: Multi dynamic routes in Children of a Route

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I have issues with Vue Router. I want to use dynamic route with `city` name and `country` name have the same baseslug: `/explore/`, example: `/explore/canada` and `/explore/los-angeles`

So I made my Router:

```
export const explore = {
  path: '/explore',
  component: Home,
  children: [
    // Single Location
    {
      path: ':country_name',
      component: CountryPage,
      name: 'CountryRoute'
    },
    {
      path: ':city_name',
      component: CityPage,
      name: 'CityRoute'
    }
  ]
}
```

When Use router:

```
<router-link :to="{ name: 'CityRoute', params: { city_name: users.live_in.slug }}">
```

It is ok, but when I reloaded by pressing F5, get error:
`Request failed with status code 404`

Comment: There is no way for the router to know which component to load in your way. Why not load the same parent component and decide whether it's city or country in the parent component ?

Comment: Thanks for your tip. I'll try it :)